# PHP image show on browser

Tags: php

(1)

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
echo '<img src="'.$file.'" />';
```

(2)

```
 $file = $_GET['file'];
 $imginfo = getimagesize($file);
 header('Content-type: '.$imginfo['mime']);
 echo file_get_contents($file);`
```

From these 2 code, my image can show in the browser nicely. But what is the differences of them? Which method should I prefer?

Answer (score 2):

The first example you've posted is simply "including" the image file into the DOM.
It would essentially output something like:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" />
```

While the second option actually sets the `Content-Type` to whatever the `mime` of the image is. Meaning if it's a `png` for example, the page that runs that script will actually be served as a whole image.

If it was a png image, it'd return the content type of `image/png`.

Answer (score 0):

The key difference is output:

Example `1` references from a path whereas example `2` outputs the binary and labels it an image (so HTTP clients can interpret the response correctly).

To the point... example `1` is preferred because it doesn't have to store the file contents in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first example you've posted is simply:
output:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

The second option actually sets the Content-Type:

It's return the content type of `image/png` or `image/jpg` like that.

I prefered go to second example.

Comment: You get the size and also content type.